# Why does Rect.Top is less than Bottom?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
Rect r = new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Point(-1, -1));
var check = r.Top > r.Bottom; //false, Top is -1
```

I thought, what Top should be greater than Bottom. Why it is not true?

Comment: In the *general* computer graphics world, the top-left corner of the coordinate plane is `(0, 0)`, which means the `Top` would *always* have to be the lower value. (Why would you expect it to create a `Top` that is further down the screen than the `Bottom`?) In this particular `Rect` class, you will never, ever, ever, ever, *ever* see a `Top` that is a bigger value than the `Bottom`, because that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that `new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Point(-1, -1))` would create a Rect with negative width and height. This is not the case.

In fact, as mentioned in the [online documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms587931.aspx), it

> initializes a new instance of the Rect structure that is exactly large enough to contain the two specified points.

A look at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Rect.cs,fc387a6f7a1c2856) of that constructor reveals how it's working.

```
public Rect(Point point1, Point point2)
{
    _x = Math.Min(point1._x, point2._x);
    _y = Math.Min(point1._y, point2._y);

    //  Max with 0 to prevent double weirdness from causing us to be (-epsilon..0)
    _width = Math.Max(Math.Max(point1._x, point2._x) - _x, 0);
    _height = Math.Max(Math.Max(point1._y, point2._y) - _y, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Point (0,0) in most computer graphics is in the top left corner and the lower you go the higher your y coordinate. Same with x coordinate when you go more to the right.

Answer (score 1):

It helps me: to read attentive the MSDN documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms587931(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Initializes a new instance of the Rect structure that is exactly large
>   enough to contain the two specified points.

This means, that first point is not mandatory left-bottom and second right/top or vice versa. It depends on Points(I want say, that left/bottom and right/top points havn't be the same as constructor's parameters)..
In your case left/bottom point is (-1,0) and right/top is (0,-1) => **bottom=0**; **top=-1**;